# Why do I need "var timer = null;" when I use "timer = setInterval();"?

Tags: javascript, timer, null, setinterval

To make an image spin by mousing over, I wrote like this.

In JavaScript,

```
var images=["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"];
var i = 0;
var timer = null;
window.onload = function() {
$("startButton").observe("mouseover", startSpin);
}
function startSpin() {
timer = setInterval(changeImage, 100);
}
function changeImage() {
i++;
if (i > 2) {
i = 0;
}
$("img").src = images[i];
}
```

Why do I need "var timer = null;" as a global variable?
I do not understand why the code does not work without this.

Comment: Technically, you don't, `var timer` would work just as well, as would leaving it out entirely (assuming you're on the top level already there, you'll be implicitly assigning to the global scope... not a good idea, but it *works*) You could also remove any references to `timer` if you wanted, since it doesn't look like the variable is actually being used anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at what it would look like without that line:

```
var images=["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"];
var i = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  $("startButton").observe("mouseover", startSpin);
}
function startSpin() {
  timer = setInterval(changeImage, 100);
}
function changeImage() {
  i++;
  if (i > 2) {
    i = 0;
  }
  $("img").src = images[i];
}
```

Without the initial `var timer = null;`, the first time `timer` is mentioned is in the `startSpin` function. There, it has no idea what `timer` is, because it's never been defined. You would need the `startSpin` function to look like this:

`function startSpin() {
  let timer = setInterval(changeImage, 100);
}`

If done this way, you shouldn't need the initial `var timer = null;`.